# NetBeans error. Don't know why

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm having a little problem with NetBeans and I haven't a clue why. I haven't used it for a week or two, but I went to use my web application today and I've been met with a lot of errors that weren't there the last time I used it.

```
<sql:query var="words" dataSource="jdbc/onlinedictionary">
    SELECT word_id, words FROM Words
</sql:query>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


    <body>

        <h1 align="center">Hello and welcome to my Online English Dictionary</h1>


    <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>This Online English Dictionary uses a 5,000 word list
                        compiled by Professor Mark Davies of Brigham Young University
                        in Provo, Utah.</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>To view a definition of a particular word, please select
                        from the list below.</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <form action="submit.jsp">
                            <strong>Select a word:</strong>
                            <select name="word_id">
                                <c:forEach var="row" items="${words.rowsByIndex}">
                                    <option><c:out value="${row[1]}"/></option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                            <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" />
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: and these errors are? Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's also stating that all of the tags are "Stray" even though there are clearly two of everything.

Comment: You'll need to post at least a summary of the error(s), and most likely a stack trace so we can see what the errors are

Comment: Sorry, some are the red squiggly lines, and others are the yellow squiggly lines. And it's saying some tags are "Stray"

Comment: Are there errors when you actually run the application, or is NetBeans just having trouble parsing the HTML?

Comment: You also need to put the <thead>, <tr>, etc tags in a <table> wrapper, this may be causing your issues

Comment: Edit your question, don't put the errors in comments.

Comment: It's having trouble parsing the HTML, but it hasn't been like this ever. And I haven't touched the code. When I run it I'm met with an error saying Unknown column in Field List.

Answer (score 0):

The error is that the db table schema was modified and that field is no longer in the db.